# children function splits expressions ambiguously in Matlab

Tags: matlab, children

The Matlab symbolic toolbox produces ambiguous answers regarding the [children](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/children.html) function.
Assume the following examples:

```
>> syms a b
>> children(a+b)
  ans = [ a, b]
>> children(a*b)
  ans = [ a, b]
>> children(a^b)
  ans = [ a, b]
```

The function split the different expressions into the same answer and even worse, Matlab does not give any hint what kind of split it did. Thus, one needs to know exactly the concatenation of the input to do the inference, how the children function was applied. Is there a way to apply something like the children function which lets you know how the term was split?

Comment: I think it would help is you described what you'e trying to accomplish to make sure we don't have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. What sort of solution are you looking for? Are you just trying to find operators in simple symbolic expressions (polynomials?)? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @horchler it is indeed an XY problem. But anyway, the ambiguity of the children function looks really messy to me. The question originates from the problem of splitting really long symbolic equations into smaller terms, where even [simplify](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify-symbolic-expressions.html) fails. In the end, I try to [code](https://de.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder.html) the functions, but the length causes the compiler to segfault. If I split the equations first, it works.

Comment: I've created a [repo](https://github.com/tik0/sym2pyfun) of the application from which the question originates. Mabe that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A naive workaround would be a function, which enhances the children function in matlab. The following might work, but there is a possibility that not all cases are covered. I am open for enhancements on this:

```
function [childs, issum, isprod, ispow, isfun] = children2(parent)
%CHILDREN2 Returns the children plus meta info. of math. concatenation
% Author: tkorthals@cit-ec.uni-bielefeld.de
% Input
%  parent                   Symbolic expression
% Output
%  childs                   Vector of symbolic expression
%  issum                    True if parent is sum of children
%  isprod                   True if parent is product of children
%  ispow                    True if parent is power of children
%  isfun                    True if parent is some function's argument

childs = children(parent);
issum = false; isprod = false; ispow = false; isfun = false;

if numel(childs) == 1
    if ~isequaln(childs,parent) % functions were removed
        isfun = true;
    end
    return
end

if numel(childs) == 2
    if isequaln(childs(1)^childs(2),parent) % pow
        ispow = true;
        return
    elseif isequaln(childs(1)/childs(2),parent) % div
        childs = parent;
        return
    end
end

if isequaln(prod(childs),parent) % prod
    isprod = true;
    return
end

if isequaln(sum(childs),parent) % sum
    issum = true;
    return
end

error('children2: Undefined behaviour for more than two children')

end
```